# admin site appearance in django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am learning django through djangobook.com. I am going step by step and everything is going as expected. when I run the local server no errors occur but the appearance of my site is a little different. while the picture examples shown by the official website include colored table and fancy headers mine just has the simple texts and links. once I was learning it in windows xp and everything was the same. The problem arise since I came to ubuntu 10.04.
Does it have anything with my python version? I am using the default version 2.6.5 .
I really appreciate if you can help me.

thanks a lot

Comment: You mean there's no CSS on the admin page?

Comment: Can you please post your `settings.py` not need to include the databases dict, that can be left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the static files required for the admin interface into your project folder.

Create a folder named `static` in your project.

Now edit the settings.py file:

```
# full path to the static directory you just created
STATIC_ROOT = 'absolute_path_to_static_directory'  

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Now run: `python manage.py collectstatic`

This will place all the admin static files into the `static` directory.

Now run your server again.

Comment: He really should not need to do `collectstatic`. I mean, I just created a static files folder, and that always works fine.

Comment: thanks for your response. yes, everything appear with no css. I tried your instructions but I just get this: Unknown command: 'collectstatic' Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac If the admin files are already on the python path then there's no need of `collectstatic`, but looks like there's something wrong with OP's django setup.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I thought so too, I mean this is supposed to work out of the box. Having a look at his project setup and files would be of great help.

Comment: @rezahs Uncomment `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in settings.py file.

Comment: exceleeeeeent Thanks. uncommenting above line worked fine. I had missed it or the tutorial? I will check it. any way thanks a lot Ashwini Chaudhary

Comment: @rezahs Glad that helped, you can accept the answer if it worked for you.